# Deploy NodeJS Express API to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

I used CodeFresh to build my Docker Image and push to AWS ECR.

[image]

I check my ECR, I can see the pushed there successfully.

[image]

I SSH into my EC2, I don't see any content there.

[image]

---

## Update

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$ docker ps                                                                                                                            
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                    COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES  
1e4d4eae6520        616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api   "sh cmd.sh"         29 hours ago        Up 29 hours         3002/tcp            ecs-api-1-bheng-api-88ef95c7ddc993badf01                                                                                                                                   
44b78781d487        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest                           "/agent"            30 hours ago        Up 30 hours                             ecs-agent                                                                                                                                                                  
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$                                                                                                                                      
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$                                                                                                                                      
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$ docker images                                                                                                                        
REPOSITORY                                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE                                           
616934057156.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api   latest              41e9eaa2aff2        29 hours ago        952MB                                          
amazon/amazon-ecs-agent                                  latest              622111e45fde        6 weeks ago         29.4MB                                         
amazon/amazon-ecs-pause                                  0.1.0               b875fd8f097a        6 weeks ago         963kB                                          
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$                                                                                                                                      
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$                                                                                                                                      
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-47 share]$
```

---

This is the security group of my *EC2*

[image]

## PM2

```
Use --update-env to update environment variables
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [all](ids: 0)
[PM2] [index](0) ✓
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ index    │ 0  │ fork │ 23901 │ online │ 1       │ 0s     │ 0%  │ 12.8 MB   │ node │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you expect the content to be in `/home`?

Comment: I don't know how to debug this whole thing. On the codefresh build show success, and the ECR side show success there also. The only thing left is my task deinition and my EC2, and I don't know where to start debug :( - any suggestions ?

Comment: Well the taskdefinition is AFAIK for the ECS, so it would create a container of the image you defined. Have you tried to run `docker ps`? If the task is running you should see a running docker image.

Comment: @vstm : Nice hints, I run `docker ps`, I saw the process there. I also run `docker images`, I saw images listed.

Comment: check ur security group is it allowing port 80 from any where as u container is running from last 29 hour

Comment: 2nd docker exec -it container_id bash then check pm2 list or forever list or what ever PM you using for nodejs ,confirm it is ur node process is running, if not then start node process, curl localhost:3002 inside contaienr

Comment: I got `node@1e4d4eae6520:/api$ curl localhost:3002
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3002: Connection refused` when I run in a container or in my EC2.

Comment: its mean node server is not running, just go to directory where u have code and start node server then use curl to debug

Comment: pm2 shows its up 0 zero second ago, its should work now

Comment: on ec2 u suppose to curl localhost:80 in container use 3002 if node server listening 3002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing

By doing `ls` does not mean it will show the docker image.

If the docker images pull successfully then check it using below command.

```
docker images
```

This will print all the images that are running in this ec2 container instance.
something like `56789.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api:latest`.

As for debugging is a concern you need to check is your docker container is running.

```
docker ps
```

This will print running container.

copy the id of the container and run this command.

```
docker exec -it {container_id} bash|ash
```

**docker logs**

```
docker logs  {container_id}
```

You can also check how images is working by assigning role to your ece container instace and run the following command.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 56789.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bheng-api:latest
```

Again I will mention the steps

> 1. create ECR and push ur docker image
> 2. create Task definition
> 3. create service that runs the instance of that task definition. with out service there will be nothing like container or docker image.
>      once u create service you will se docker image in your ec2 instance.

You can also view tasks events using AWS console under ECS -> cluster -> service -> tasks

If some thing went wrong you will see in the events like

[image]

If every thing ok then

[image]

Complete image

[image]

Comment: `-bash: ash: command not found ` I tried one for your command.

Comment: if image is alpine u need to use ash or if other then use bash

Comment: got. it. amazing answer by the way. I'm sure your answer will help a lot of people like me.

Comment: My task, say INACTIVE. :( I am trying to make sure my API is reachable.

Comment: task inactive mean not runing by any service or check ur securty group is it allowing port

Comment: Does it switch between active and inactive? What does the event-tab of the task say?

Comment: event tab say the main story is task runing or not and if fail then whats the reason u can check the log ,can show ur logs

Comment: I uploaded what I have as my sec group. I hope I did it correct.

Comment: its look fine. allow form any where another thing check ur node process is it running or not

Comment: What wrong with what I did that make my node server is not started like that.  ?

Comment: Do I need to create .env file in on my container ?

Comment: no, there is an option for env in the task definition. define ur env in ur task definition instead of env file

Comment: still problem persist @kyo